# How to compare day from the ctime lib with a day string?

Tags: c++, time

does anyone know how to compare the day with day string..  It might sound confusing but I had this thing in mind.. Hope the code clears everything out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
    int main()
    {
        /// current date/time based on current system
        time_t now = time(0);

        /// convert now to string form
       tm *ltm = localtime(&now);


        cout << "The local date and time is: " << ltm << endl;

        if(*ltm == "Mon") Monday();
        else if(*ltm == "Tue") Tuesday();
        else if(*ltm == "Wed") Wednesday();
        else if(*ltm == "Thu") Thursday();
        else if(*ltm == "Fri") Friday();
        else if(*ltm == "Sat" || *ltm == "Sun") Monday();




        return 0;
    }
```

and that's the one of the huge error message board,I'm giving just that one line because the rest of the errors are the same but for different lines.

```
/home/shadowdragon/Documents/uktc_schdule/UKTC_schedule/main.cpp|90|error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘tm’ and ‘const char [4]’)|
```

Comment: These are numbers, not strings. You probably want to read the [reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm) first before using that strcuct.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ You meant [this reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm), right? Because the one that is being used in the question is of C (not C++)... For C++, we can use [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/gmtime) function instead of `localtime()`... (And it gives [*UTC*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), so that's better in a way)

Comment: @Ruks It doesn't matter much IMO. Both documentations clearly show the OPs misconception with the `tm` struct.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ It is probably best to use `std::tm` either way since `c++` is in the tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You don't even need to compare it with a string (viz. `const char*`)... `<ctime>` provides its own method to compare all that...

First, make an enumerator that keeps track of all days of the week (0-6),

```
enum
{
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday
};
```

Now check it like this:

```
if (*ltm.tm_wday == Sunday)
    std::cout << "Its Sunday!" << std::endl;
```

Do the same for the other days as well...

If you look closely, you can see that the struct member **tm_wday** returns a number between the range *0-6* (*Sunday* to *Monday*) and the *enumerator is just to clarify it*... (So that you don't get confused with `if (*ltm.tm_wday == 0 /*Sunday*/)` or something like that...)

See more about the *tm* structure [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm)...

There is even a C++ alternative [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm)...

**Note:** `std::tm` gives you the accurate UTC time, so it is recommended to check it out, and use [this function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/gmtime) instead of `localtime()` as pointed out in the comments section...

---

**Edit:** If you *have* to compare it with a string... then maybe a function can be of help...

```
const char * GetDay(struct tm * tm)
{
    switch (tm->tm_wday)
    {
        case 0:
            return "Sun";
        case 1:
            return "Mon";
        case 2:
            return "Tue";
        case 3:
            return "Wed";
        case 4:
            return "Thu";
        case 5:
            return "Fri";
        case 6:
            return "Sat";
        default: return "";
    }
}
```

Then do something like:

```
if (GetDay(ltm) == "Sun")
    std::cout << "Its Sunday again!" << std::endl;
```

Kind regards,

Ruks.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer @Ruks, but Now i have another error, that function definition is not allowed before '{' token.. I know it might be stupid questions and stuff but I'm new to C++ and I just want to try stuff so I can improve myself.. Again Thank you for the answer!

Comment: never mind found my mistake, Thanks again for the help @Ruks!